# ManateeSerializer ManateeActionData does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, trello, manatee.trello

Trello Manatee API 3.0.7 is throwing an error during my initialize method:

```
var serializer = new ManateeSerializer();

TrelloConfiguration.Serializer = serializer;
TrelloConfiguration.Deserializer = serializer;
TrelloConfiguration.JsonFactory = new ManateeFactory();
TrelloConfiguration.RestClientProvider = new WebApiClientProvider();
TrelloAuthorization.Default.AppKey = "[My App Key]";
TrelloAuthorization.Default.UserToken = "[My User Token]";
```

The following exception is thrown after the first line initializing ManateeSerializer():

Method 'get_CustomField' in type 'Manatee.Trello.ManateeJson.Entities.ManateeActionData' from assembly 'Manatee.Trello.ManateeJson, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fbb8336f4f768592' does not have an implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of v3.0.0, the JSON and REST implementations have been integrated into the main library as defaults.  You don't need to configure these anymore.

There are also quite a few other changes.  Please read the new doucmentation [here](https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Trello/index.html).

If you have any other question, I have a Slack link at the top of the README, or you can open an issue on the repo.